# Jenkins junit results coming empty

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using jenkins Jenkins 2.277.4 and junit plugin 1.51
My jenkinsfile code has below snippet for junit

```
 junit allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: "${COMPONENT}/*_test_report.xml"
```

I have check the file ${COMPONENT}/*_test_report.xml  and it is non empty.
but I am getting results in pipeline as

```
Recording test results
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
```

I have tried upgrading the plugin , not sure what is wrong I am doing here ?

Comment: I don't think this error is related directly to a junit error, but you can try to run the `junit` step with `skipPublishingChecks: true` to see if it solves your issue.

Comment: I can paste the xml which has results , Any idea why such behavior will come ?

Comment: Take a look at [This Issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/checks-api-plugin/issues/38) may be related.

Answer (score 1):

From the https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit/ docs, use the  `skipPublishingChecks: true` argument to disable publishing warnings back to your SCM provider.